# Can you decipher this structure please?

Tags: grammar

> Of course, you can also choose to have your grades emailed to you.

In the above sentence, what is the grammatical role of "have"? What is the name of the grammar structure? I expect to see "be emailed to you" but the simple form of "email" is used.

Comment: I fixed the mistake: emailed. To have something done [past participle] for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "Of course, you can also choose to have your grades email**ed** to you."

Looking at this dictionary entry http://www.dictionary.com/browse/have , it seems to be definition 6

> to cause to, as by command or invitation

or possibly 4

> to experience, undergo, or endure, as joy or pain:

This is a causative structure; see https://www.espressoenglish.net/causative-verbs-in-english-let-make-have-get-help/

> HAVE = Give Someone Else The Responsibility To Do Something
>   
> Grammatical structure:
>
> HAVE + PERSON + VERB (base form)
>   HAVE + THING + PAST PARTICIPLE OF VERB
>
> Examples of grammatical structure #1:
>
> I’ll have my assistant call you to reschedule the appointment.
>   The businessman had his secretary make copies of the report.
>
> Examples of grammatical structure #2:
>
> I’m going to have my hair cut tomorrow.
>   We’re having our house painted this weekend.
>   Bob had his teeth whitened; his smile looks great!
>   My washing machine is broken; I need to have it repaired.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me, too

Comment: Here is the original voice of that sentence: https://clyp.it/fiq3frqy
Do you believe the speaker has made a mistake regarding the "email*ed*?

Comment: The speaker definitely said "...emailed to you," but the **d** at the end of "emailed" has been almost completely elided into the **t** of the word "to."   If you listen very carefully, you can hear the vowel sound of the syllable "ed" at the end of "emailed."

Comment: @CanadianYankee That's right. I hear it.